# mysql - global disable update of primary key column

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Is it possible to disable the possibility to update a primary key column on global level via global session or server variable?

Or do I need to manually check it an update trigger in each table?

Comment: So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, by what exactly is "primary key update"?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux: I think that refers to an `UPDATE` that sets the value of a column contained in a PRIMARY KEY constraint to a new value.

Comment: sorry for my bad language, updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not possible to prohibit an update to a column that is part of a "primary key" constraint, using a global, server, session, et al. variable.

If you want to prevent an UPDATE statement from making a change, you could try enforcing that with a BEFORE UPDATE trigger on each table.

```
SET NEW.primary_key_col = OLD.primary_key_col;
```

---

FOLLOWUP:

dmjm says: "**I would rather throw an error** ..."

To throw an error from a trigger using MySQL 5.5 or later, you can use the new `SIGNAL` syntax.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

With MySQL 5.1 or earlier, there's no direct way to throw an error, so developers implemented "bad"  code that is executed to (virtually) guarantee an error is thrown.

```
IF ( NEW.primary_key_col <> OLD.primary_key_col ) THEN
  UPDATE `Error: primary_key_col modification not allowed` SET dummy=0 WHERE dummy=-1;
END IF;
```

Comment: I would rather throw an error signal since other columns could also be updated within same statement.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to the answer of spencer7593, if you manage yourself the users of your DB, you could always "protect" some columns by using [`REVOKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html):

```
REVOKE UPDATE (primary_key_col) ON db.tbl FROM 'user'@'localhost'
```